# How to read ORC file metadata?

Tags: go, orc

I am trying to read an ORC file using the Go [`github.com/scritchley/orc`](https://github.com/scritchley/orc) package.
I am able to read the content of the ORC file but I also wanted to read the ORC metadata. I can't find a straight forward of doing that with the package.

The example from the package:

```
r, err := orc.Open(localFileName)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer r.Close()
logging.Info("reader returned")

// Create a new Cursor reading the provided columns.
c := r.Select()

// Iterate over each stripe in the file.
for c.Stripes() {

    // Iterate over each row in the stripe.
    for c.Next() {

        // Retrieve a slice of interface values for the current row.
        log.Println(c.Row())

    }

}

if err := c.Err(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Your code is just a copy of the readme example. The package says it's still a work in progress; perhaps ask on GitHub if/when/how metadata is supported.

Comment: i didn't try anything. I was not able to figure out from the code on how to get the user metadata.